# How much RAM does the 4th Gen iPod Touch have?

Tags: ipod-touch

How much RAM do these iPods ship with?

The iPhone 4 has 512MB, and older iPod Touch 3rd Gen have 256MB (same as the iPad).

Do the new iPod Touch have 512MB as the iPhone 4 (what I would expect) or 256MB?

Comment: I'd expect 512MB too, otherwise the retina display will eat it all.

Comment: @rjstelling The iPad has a higher resolution but only has 256MB memory

Comment: Wikipedia says 512MB but also [citation needed] xD who knows?

Comment: @Kyle - Does iPad really only have 256mb? I thought it has 512

Comment: @Moshe Nope, just 256. Look under the "memory" section of the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad).

Comment: As was said, the unit carries 256 MB of RAM (same as the original iPad). This, however, rarely hinders the unit if you've ever had a chance to play with one mostly because the lack of cellular technology. The cellular components in the iPhones put quite a bit of load on the unit, much more than any other system in the phone. The 256 MB are more than enough to handle the load of the new display (as was mentioned above) or any other system on the Touch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[According to iFixit](http://twitter.com/iFixit/status/23943771042), the 4th gen iPod Touch has 256MB, not 512MB like the iPhone 4.:

> Breaking news: the iPod Touch has only 256 MB RAM, same Samsung part markings as iPad.

Comment: Just saw this myself... sad to hear. I still wonder if the memory is the same for the three versions, but that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

In a tear down [Apple Insider](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/09/08/teardown_of_apples_4th_gen_ipod_touch_finds_256mb_of_ram.html) found the 4th Gen iPod touch has 256mb

Answer (score 0):

256 MB. [[iFixit]](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPod-Touch-4th-Generation-Teardown/3562/3)

Comment: Wikipedia now says 256MB, and doesn't include the [citation needed]. Maybe someone there confirmed it.